# tracking affiliates in mixpanel

Tags: affiliate, mixpanel

Trying to use mixpanel to set up a basic affiliate tracking system.

No problem setting up referral links and tracking events through the segmentation system, however I want to be able to attribute a certain event to a refferer even if the event is triggered in a later session (e.g the classic 30 day cookie for a standard affiliate program).

Anyone know how to go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a [super property](https://mixpanel.com/docs/properties-or-segments/how-do-i-set-a-property-every-time).

Answer (score 0):

Building on raylu's answer you certainly want a super property: [How do I set a property every time?](https://mixpanel.com/docs/properties-or-segments/how-do-i-set-a-property-every-time)

For affiliates you likely want to only count the first affiliate so you want to use `register_once`: https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/javascript-full-api#register_once